# Python csv write a list to file

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a script to write a list with tab separated  as below to a csv file. But i am not getting proper output on this.

```
out_l = ['host\tuptime\tnfsserver\tnfs status\n', 'node1\t2\tnfs_host\tok\n', 'node2\t100\tnfs_host\tna\n', 'node3\t59\tnfs_host\tok\n']
```

code:

```
out_f = open('test.csv', 'w')
w = csv.writer(out_f)

for l in out_l:
    w.writerow(l)
out_f.close()
```

The output csv file reads as below.

```
h,o,s,t,    ,s,s,h, , , , , ,s,u,d,o,_,h,o,s,t, , , , , , , ,n,f,s,"
"1,9,2,.,1,6,8,.,1,2,2,.,2,0,1, ,o,k,   ,n,f,s,h,o,s,t, ,o,k,"
"1,9,2,.,1,6,8,.,1,2,2,.,2,0,2, ,f,a,i,l,e,d,   ,n,a,   ,n,a,"
"1,9,2,.,1,6,8,.,1,2,2,.,2,0,3, ,o,k,   ,n,f,s,h,o,s,t, ,s,h,o,w,m,o,u,n,t, ,f,a,i,l,e,d,"
```

"

Also I have checked the csv.writer option like delimiter, dialect=excel, but no luck.
Can some one help to format the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the formatting you have in `out_l`, you can just write it to a file:

```
out_l = ['host\tuptime\tnfsserver\tnfs status\n', 'node1\t2\tnfs_host\tok\n', 'node2\t100\tnfs_host\tna\n', 'node3\t59\tnfs_host\tok\n']

with open('test.csv', 'w') as out_f:
    for l in out_l:
        out_f.write(l)
```

To properly use `csv`, `out_l` should just be lists of the columns and let the `csv` module do the formatting with tabs and newlines:

```
import csv

out_l = [['host','uptime','nfsserver','nfs status'],
         ['node1','2','nfs_host','ok'],
         ['node2','100','nfs_host','na'],
         ['node3','59','nfs_host','ok']]

#with open('test.csv', 'wb') as out_f:           # Python 2
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_f: # Python 3
    w = csv.writer(out_f, delimiter='\t')        # override for tab delimiter
    w.writerows(out_l)                           # writerows (plural) doesn't need for loop
```

Note that `with` will automatically close the file.

See the [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for the correct way to open a file for use with `csv.reader` or `csv.writer`.

Answer (score 2):

The `csv.Writer.writerow` method takes an iterable and writes the values said iterable produces into the csv fields separated by the specified delimeter:

```
out_f = open('test.csv', 'w')
w = csv.writer(out_f, delimiter='\t')  # set tab as delimiter

for l in out_l:  # l is string (iterable of chars!)
    w.writerow(l.split('\t'))  # split to get the correct tokens
out_f.close()
```

As the strings in your list already contain the necessary tabs, you could just write them directly to the file, no csv tools needed. If you have built/joined the strings in `out_l` manually, you can omit that step and just pass the original data structure to `writerow`.

Comment: If commas are a must, you can search and replace the tabs with commas in your list, then use shwobaseggl's method, setting the comma as the delimiter instead.

Comment: It Worked. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

## The `delimiter` parameter

The `delimiter` parameter controls the delimiter in the **output**. It has nothing to do with the input `out_l`.

## Why your output is garbled

`csv.writer.writerow` iterates the input. In your case you are giving it a string (`host\tuptime\tnfsserver\tnfs status\n'`, etc.), therefore the function iterates the string, giving you a sequence of chars.

## How to produce the correct output

Give it a list of fields instead of the full string by using `str.split()`. In your case the string ends with `\n`, so use `str.strip()` as well:

```
import csv

out_l = ['host\tuptime\tnfsserver\tnfs status\n',
         'node1\t2\tnfs_host\tok\n',
         'node2\t100\tnfs_host\tna\n',
         'node3\t59\tnfs_host\tok\n']
out_f = open('test.csv', 'w')
w = csv.writer(out_f)
for l in out_l:
    w.writerow(l.strip().split('\t'))
out_f.close()
```

This should be what you want:

```
host,uptime,nfsserver,nfs status
node1,2,nfs_host,ok
node2,100,nfs_host,na
node3,59,nfs_host,ok
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
with open("test.csv" , 'w') as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delemeter='\t')
     for item in out_l:
          writer.writerow([item,])
```